# Complex Line integral of 1/z over the principle branch cut

Tags: integration, logarithms, branch-cuts, line-integrals

I would appreciate it if someone checked my work to ensure that it's consistent.

> Compute the integral $\int_{C}\frac 1 z {dz}$ by obtaining an appropriate branch of the logarithm.

There's an image provided showing an unspecified point in quadrant III creating a line towards another unspecified point in quadrant II.

Let the branch of $\text{Log}(z)$ be defined as $0 \lt \arg(z) \lt 2\pi$, which implies that the branch is defined by the positive real axis.

$\int_{C}\frac 1 z {dz}$ where $z\neq 0$ and $ z\not\in\Bbb R^+$

Then for some starting point $z_i$ in quadrant III and some ending point $z_o$ in quadrant II, $z$ can be parametrized:

$x = x_i + x_ot$

$y = y_i + y_ot$

$z = x_i + x_ot + i(y_i + y_ot) = z_i + z_ot$, where $0 \le t \le 1$

$dz = z_odt$

$\int_0^1 \frac {1} {z_i + z_o} z_odt = [\text{Log}(z_i + z_ot)]_0^1 = \text{Log}(z_i + z_o) - \text{Log}(z_i)$

Would someone mind explaining the topology of this as well? I've always assumed that line integrals were path independent. If the branch cut was defined by $-\pi \lt \arg(z) \lt \pi$, could an arc parametrization be created to integrate around the branch cut from $z_i$ to $z_o$? This isn't what the assignment asked, but I'm curious.  Thanks!

Comment: line integrals are path independent as long as you don't cross any singularity

Comment: in your case, try another path from $z_o$ to $z_i$ with whatever parametrization you want and show that it is $-$ your result so that the closed path integral yields $0$. You can also try parametrizations which cross the cut and see what happens...

Comment: So you're saying create a simple closed curve with the principle branch defined for an arc around the branch and try to show that the addition of the both the line and the arc equals zero? Assuming both have the same direction.

Comment: yes sir! i hope this convinces you that everything is expected. If not, Cauchy,s theorem will answer all your questions ;)

Comment: I appreciate your help. I'll try that.